How to get into second frame in recording mode in kataon?
My team searched and we found a way where we switched into manual mode, but now we can`t get back to record mode so I need one of two either to know how to back to record mode or to know how to get to second frame without leaving the record mode.
We found a solution where we used some scripts, but we could not back to recording mode and we were expecting to test the hole project in record mode.
The code which we used in scripting mode is:
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.By as By
import *org.openqa.selenium.Keys* as Keys
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory as DriverFactory
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.*getWebDriver*()
driver.switchTo().frame(1)
driver.findElement(By.*cssSelector*("#pane\_ \> ul:nth-child(1) \> li \> span")).click()

